# Android TextView in ListView blinking when showing long message

Tags: android

I have a list view that contain a textview inside. I want to show a very long message (maybe about 5000 chars) in the textview. The problem is, when I scroll down/up the listview, the text inside the textview will be blinking and some time won't show up. What do I need to do to prevent this to happen?

Comment: then draw the text in a custom view,  see StaticLayout class

Comment: Are you trying to scroll the `ListView` in an Android 2.x? Could you share code and/or screenshot/video?